# Limiting permissions of a file owner

Tags: bash

I would like some assistance on what happens when you set the ownership of a file for the owner. AKA. chmod 400 would mean only the owner can view it and no one else can do anything with it. However, if I open vim (as that owner user) and make change to the file, I am able to write to it by using "wq!". So what exactly do these permissions limit if the user can overwrite them? Am I also able to overrwrite the permissions in other tools than vim (aka righting to the file from a program)?

Answer (score 5):

The system is working exactly as intended and following your explicit instructions.

With the `!` you are telling vim to *just do as I say, I know what I'm doing*. As you are the owner of the file you can change permission to allow writes so this is in effect what vim will do.

Answer (score 2):

Make the file immutable with [**chattr**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html) i.e. `chattr +i yourfile`. Then no one will be able to change it, not even root, unless the attribute is unset. Note that only root can set or unset this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the owner of the file (or the root user) you can ignore file permissions.  Although, as you have already seen, that does require an override switch (the `!` in vim) to force the issue as the normal behaviour is of course to honour file system permissions. Many or maybe even most programs are not designed with such an override.

That makes the normal `rwx` type of permissions *discretionary access controls* , they depend partly on the implicit trust that software is well behaved.

Mandatory access controls, such as SELinux, can enforce correct behaviour, even when software is misbehaving.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true.  It's true that `vim` is bright enough to nip round the back and do a temporary chmod for the duration of the write (which is something the file owner is completely allowed to do, and thus so are his/her software agents), but without that intelligence on the software's part, writes to a 400 file simply fail, and directory lookups in a 000 directory fail likewise.  I see file permissions as much MACs as SELinux controls: both can be changed by the appropriate person(s), and until they are, both will block something that isn't permitted.